# python : how to import packages?

Tags: python, sys.path

This is my folder:

```
/Workspace
 somefiles.py
          /foopackage
           __init__.py
           foo1.py
           foo2.py
```

And the **_*init*_**.py contains

```
from foo1 import foo1
from foo2 import foo2
```

And I want to import foopackage.
I have tried this:

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.path.append('/home/username/Workspace')
>>>import foopackage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/Workspace/foopackage/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo1 import foo1
ImportError: No module named 'foo1'
```

I have tried sys.path.append('/home/username/Workspace/foopackage') instead and the thing fixed.

I'm asking do I have to add every package directory to sys.path list to be able to import them?
or something else is wrong?

Comment: How you tried `from foopackage.foo1 import foo1`?

Comment: i've tried the below answer and it worked just right. just needed a dot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Python 3, you need to use explicit relative imports rather than implicit ones, which used to work in Python 2. Try updating `foopackage`'s `__init__.py` file to be:

```
from .foo1 import foo1
from .foo2 import foo2
```

The leading `.` characters tell Python that `foo1` and `foo2` are sibling modules, rather than being top level modules that you're referring to absolutely. An alternative would be to use an absolute reference to them:

```
from foopackage.foo1 import foo1
from foopackage.foo2 import foo2
```

But personally, I think that's a bit excessive. It will also break if you change the package name at some point in the future (or move to be a subpackage of some other package).

See [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more details on the changes to relative imports.